# Installer reboots without any reboot prompt

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, prerequisites, .net-4.8

we are trying to install an update for .net framework 4.8 as part of pre-requisites. However when installing the setup, it reboots the machine without any pop-up even after giving /norestart

The following is the command given in 'Application To Run' tab.

```
/q /norestart /log "%temp%\dotNetFx48-KB4519568.log"
```

Return code to reboot is given as

```
1641, 3010
```

The same command is given for other .NET installation (.net 4.8 and other update for 4.8). But either it asks for reboot or it silently passes the installation, only for this particular update it reboots without any request.

Answer (score 0):

I would report this to Microsoft if you can? That looks like a preview rollup package, are you sure you really need it? Perhaps you could wait for the final version?

There might be a custom action doing this - and then it does not help to pass parameters to the MSI components (if any) - but you can also try to use the **`/msioptions switch`** to pass property settings to the MSI file - that would be something like:

```
/msioptions "REBOOT=ReallySuppress"
```

The above is untested by me. Might test later, or let us know how you go. The switch is listed when you go **`setup.exe /?`** on the setup.exe file that shows up if you unzip the original exe.

[About the Reboot property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/reboot).

Comment: ya it will work for setup.exe. But usually /norestart is the keyword which we give for pre-requisite silent install. The interesting thing here is, in a Win10 and Win 7 pro machine it asks for a reboot whereas in Win7 enterprise and embedded version, it reboots without any notification. As you suggested I will try to report it to Microsoft.

Comment: Beginning with 4.5 MS gave the option to close any open .Net apps. It's a long shot here but have you tried using the /showrmui switch to see if something is being used?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/deployment-guide-for-developers